# Can I use the explicit operator to create a derived class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, explicit

```
class Base
{
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    public static explicit operator Derived1(Derived2 d2)
    {
        return new Derived1();
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Base bd2 = new Derived2();

        Derived1 d2ConvertedD1 = (Derived1)bd2; //throws InvalidCastException

    }
}
```

> `Unable to cast object of type 'ConsoleApplication1.Derived2' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.Derived1'.`

Why? What is wrong with my operator conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the signature of your operator:

```
public static explicit operator Derived1(Derived2 d2);
```

Notice it's **static**. What you're seeing is similar to the limitation of method overload resolution.

It's essentially the same reason the below outputs "Object" instead of "String":

```
static void WriteObject(object obj) { Console.WriteLine("Object"); }
static void WriteObject(string str) { Console.WriteLine("String"); }

object obj = "I am a string.";
WriteObject(obj);
```

That is, the compiler needs to pick an overload at compile-time. In the case of casting from a `Base` to a `Derived1`, there is no overload with the proper signature, so it attempts an actual downcast. Declaring `bd2` as `Derived2`, as others have mentioned, would "fix" this by enabling the compiler to select your custom conversion.

Comment: Now `dynamic` would change this :-)

Answer (score 10):

The trouble is that your custom conversion isn't being used, because the compile-time type of `bd2` is `Base`, not `Derived2`. The compiler isn't even considering your custom conversion, so it's just including a normal cast - which is failing for the obvious reason. (I assume you understand that failure, otherwise you wouldn't have created the custom conversion to start with.)

Operators and conversions are chosen by the compiler based on the *compile-time* types of the operands.

While you *could* cast to `Derived2` first or change the declaration of `bd2`, I would personally change tack completely, and look at the bigger picture again. What are you trying to do, and why? Would a virtual method in `Base` make more sense, for example?

Comment: That is just an abstract thinking, there are no any business usage here. I'm just want to know better casting operator (though they are not recommended to use). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can only cast classes up and down the hierarchy, not across.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question. The OP has created a custom operator in order to perform the conversion - but it's not being called, which is what's confusing him.

Comment: I think the title may have changed since I answered it.

Comment: It has, but I don't think the question's changed very significantly :)

Answer (score 0):

The class Derived2 does not inherit from the class Derived1, that is why this fails.

The following would be valid:

> Base d2ConvertedBase = (Base) bd2;

If Derived2 was to inherit from Derived1, what you tried would be valid.

Comment: See my comment to bjornars - the point is that the custom conversion isn't being called.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The original post was somewhat hard to decipher without that lovely C# formatting but no excuse for my less than thorough reading

Answer (score 0):

Cast to the base class. If you're creating a complex class heirarchy, consider implementing  interfaces and doing interface based programming.